# issue to connect to ssh tunel navicat using localhost

Tags: mysql, localhost, navicat

I try to connect to a distant DB server using Navicat but the Localhost generates the error "#1045 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
before it worked even if the localhost doesn't contain the username , so I tried to create them but the issue still unchanged.

Comment: Hi, why is this tagged with phpmyadmin and ssh even though you don't mention either in your post?

Comment: Are you using an SSH tunnel or connecting directly to MySQL?

Comment: Hi, I use the tunel. Before It had running perfectly after I had restarted the computer this issue has appeared YTD. I use in the "Authentification method" Public key , and the private PATH in the "private Key" in the SSH TAB , and in the General TAB I use the ip localhost, my user and a password to access to the database ip in the SSH.

Comment: Try to SSH to the remote machine (using the same private key you're giving to Navicat) and manually start the `mysql` command line client to see if you're able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Isaac , I`ve talked with the admin , he explain me that he change my user configuration from % access to Localhost. At first it didn't work for localhost for this reason he put % and after months soundainly my user has generated this issue. it's ok now, it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin has changed my acces from '%' to localhost and it's work.